# System limits for child processes in linux

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am currently reading Michael Kerrisk "The Linux programming interface". In chapter dedicated to system limits it is written:

> SUSv3 requires that the value returned by **sysconf**() for a particular
>       limit be constant for the lifetime of the calling process.

Does that mean that if I get current system limits and use them somehow in the current process, It is a rule of good taste to get them again in a child process after **fork**?

Comment: "Good taste" is not a metric that SO likes to use, folks can be quite picky here.  But yes, it strikes me as an appropriate idiom to refresh these now-stale values after the `fork()`.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, yes. If you want a dynamic value that reflects the actual limit set on a particular process, it's best to call `sysconf()` once per process.

However, some configuration values will certainly not change. For example, `PAGESIZE` won't be changing between calls to `fork()`. Invoking `sysconf()` again may not be necessary.